# ApiPlatform serialize exception

Tags: api-platform.com

I use ApiPlatform and my domain (DDD) can throw an exception like

```
final class QuotaExceededException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct(
        private int $cost,
        private int $quotaLeft,
        string $message
    ) {
        parent::__construct($message);
    }

    public function getCost(): int
    {
        return $this->cost;
    }

    public function getQuotaLeft(): int
    {
        return $this->quotaLeft;
    }
}
```

I found how to customize the http code for that exception but i would like to return also a payload like

```
{
    "type": "https:\/\/tools.ietf.org\/html\/rfc2616#section-10",
    "title": "An error occurred",
    "detail": "The message thrown",
    "cost": 10,
    "quotaLeft": 2
}
```

I tried to implement specific Normalizer (`QuotaExceededExceptionNormalizer`) but it seems that each exceptions thrown are converted to `FlattenException` which keep only the exception message and `cost` and `quotaLeft` informations are lost.

Have you any idea ?

Comment: Generally in REST relam you take advantage of HTTP status codes. You need to tell your client that quotas are problem with 409 or 428 depending on your usecase. In layman's terms, you should be using RESTfulness instead of fighting it. Regardless api-platform removes all data from exception and if you want custom response, implement controller by yourself, then it'll defy being REST complaint in true manner, choice is yours.

Comment: The issue is i want to add extra values in the payload, of course i use http status code, but with my example i want to provide more informations than just "No quota left"